# How to sort the following xml according to the name alphabetically and convert it into the JSON in Java?

Tags: java, json, xml

```
<breakfast_menu>
<food>
    <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
    <price>$5.95</price>
    <description>
    Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup
    </description>
    <calories>650</calories>
</food>
<food>
    <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
    <price>$7.95</price>
    <description>
    Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream
    </description>
    <calories>900</calories>
</food>
<food>
    <name>Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</name>
    <price>$8.95</price>
    <description>
    Light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream
    </description>
    <calories>900</calories>
</food>
<food>
    <name>French Toast</name>
    <price>$4.50</price>
    <description>
    Thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread
    </description>
    <calories>600</calories>
</food>
</breakfast_menu>
```

I am getting stucked while sorting the xml alphabetically and convert it into the JSON array.
The breakfast_menu needs to be sorted by name

Comment: Alphabetically on what key? The `name` tag contents?  What environment? How are you processing the XML? DOM or stream? Is XSL involved?  You have provided almost no context, so it is going to be impossible to figure out what you want to do.  Also, you are expected to show what you have already tried and why your efforts are not working.  Please visit the [help].

Comment: Hi Jim, I have mentioned below that I need to sort this according to <name>  tag. I need this using DOM or SAX parser in Java please

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Java 8**, you should check out my open source library: [unXml](https://github.com/tajakobsen/unxml). unXml basically maps from Xpaths to Json-attributes.

It's available on [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cunxml).

*Example*

```
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import com.nerdforge.unxml.factory.ParsingFactory;
import com.nerdforge.unxml.parsers.Parser;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class Parser {
    public List<JsonNode> parseXml(String xml){
        Document document = parsing.xml().document(xml);

        // parsing xml to Json
        Parser<ArrayNode> parser = parsing.arr("/breakfast_menu/food")
          .attribute("name")
          .attribute("price")
          .attribute("description")
          .attribute("calories")
          .build();

          ArrayNode jsonArray = parser.apply(document);

          // sorting
          List<JsonNode> result = StreamSupport.stream(jsonArray.spliterator(), false)
            .sorted((first, second) -> first.get("name").asText().compareTo(second.get("name").asText()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return result;
    }
}
```

It will return a List of [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) `JsonNode`.

```
[{
    "price" : "$5.95",
    "name" : "Belgian Waffles",
    "description" : " Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup ",
    "calories" : "650"
}, 
{
    "price" : "$8.95",
    "name" : "Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles",
    "description" : " Light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream ",
    "calories" : "900"
}, 
{
    "price" : "$4.50",
    "name" : "French Toast",
    "description" : " Thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread ",
    "calories" : "600"
}, 
{
    "price" : "$7.95",
    "name" : "Strawberry Belgian Waffles",
    "description" : " Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream ",
    "calories" : "900"
}]
```